# Getting a true variable instead of a false in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm hoping someone can see where I'm going wrong.
I have 3 pricing values `projectBudget`, `projectOverflow`, `projectTotal`, and what I'm trying to do is to create
a check that will set a variable to true or false.
So if my `projectTotal` is greater then the `projectBudget` but less then `projectOverflow` I need to set my `projectWarning` variable to true
but if my `projectTotal` is greater then `projectBudget` and it's greater then `projectOverflow` I then need to set my `projectDanger`
variable to true and my `projectWarning` to false.

The issue I'm having is that my `projectWarning` is true and my `projectDanger` is false even though my `projectTotal` is greater then
`projectBudget` and `projectOverflow`

Here is my code

```
$projectBudget = number_format((float)$project->budget, 2) // 1
$projectOverflow = number_format((float)$project->overflow, 2) // 2
$projectTotal = number_format((float)$project->total, 2) // 1234

$projectWarning = false;
$projectDanger = false;

if($projectTotal > $projectBudget && $projectTotal < $projectOverflow)
{
    $projectWarning = true;
}

if($projectTotal > $projectOverflow)
{
    $projectDanger = true;
}

dd($projectWarning , $projectDanger);
```

Comment: Drop `number_format` part as it returns _string_ and not _int_ and strings comparison with `<` may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `number_format` from your code.

Comparative operators do not work with it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

https://stevesohcot.medium.com/how-i-resolved-the-php-error-with-comparing-numbers-using-number-format-5bb081bf94a

Comment: Can you please add some explanation on why OP should do this?

Comment: Answer is UPDATED

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with just the first part of your code:

```
$project = new class {
    public $budget = 1;
    public $overflow = 2;
    public $total = 1234;
};

$projectBudget = number_format((float)$project->budget, 2); // 1
$projectOverflow = number_format((float)$project->overflow, 2); // 2
$projectTotal = number_format((float)$project->total, 2); // 1234

var_dump($projectBudget, $projectOverflow, $projectTotal);
```

If you look at the var_dump output, you'll see that the comments of the different variables are wrong - because you've called `number_format`, the variables now hold *strings*, "1.00", "2.00", and "1,234.00".

So now when you compare those variables, you're comparing strings, which will look at which one comes first in alphabetical order - clearly not what you intended.

The fix is simple: don't format numbers until you're actually presenting them to a user.